# I'm getting error while building expo app for ios

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I have run this command `exp build:ios`.
I selected Expo to handle the process.
after putting credentials Distribution Certificate, Identifiers and Provisioning Profile has been created after that the following error I'm getting:

```
? Will you provide your Distribution Certificate? Let Expo handle the process
? Will you provide your own Push Certificate? Let Expo handle the process

[18:32:36] Error while gathering & validating credentials
[18:32:36] Error: Request failed with status code 410
[18:32:36] Request failed with status code 410
[18:32:36] Error: Request failed with status code 410
    at createError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/exp/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/exp/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/exp/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:236:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:201:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1130:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:17)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can I log in to Apple Developer Site successfully?

Or, you might encounter this issue because you need to sign a new privacy agreement.

Also make sure `exp` is up to date.

Comment: Thanks, buddy, after updating the expo app build successfully.